# Outputting Disk Usage in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am fairly new to Powershell scripting and I have a task that I need to achieve every week for a large list of clients.

I am looking at outputting the storage usage/capacity on each server.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" |
Select-Object -Property DeviceID,
@{L='FreeSpaceGB';E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace /1GB)}},
@{L="Capacity";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}
```

The above code does what I want, however it outputs it like this:

```
DeviceID FreeSpaceGB Capacity
-------- ----------- --------
C:       74.91       231.72
```

I was hoping it to look more like:

```
C: 74.91GB/231.72GB
```

Is it possible to use Select-String to select the output of the above code, and then use that string to give the output I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **format string** to get your desired output:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | ForEach-Object {
    '{0} {1:N2}GB/{2:N2}GB' -f $_.DeviceId, ($_.FreeSpace /1GB),($_.Size/1GB) 
}
```

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | ForEach-Object {
    '{0} {1:N2}GB/{2:N2}GB' -f $_.DeviceId, ($_.FreeSpace /1GB),($_.Size/1GB) 
}
C: 162.98GB/476.34GB
D: 1,814.17GB/3,726.01GB

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | ForEach {
  "$($_.DeviceId) $($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)GB/$($_.Size / 1GB)GB"
}
```

Comment: Your command sort of worked, however it removed the rounding.